# Reverse querying

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, query

Is it possible to run a reverse query?  In other words, I have a master shapefile and a derived shapefile containing data extracted from the master file, but don't know what criteria the extraction was based on.  Is there a tool or process that will tell how the master shapefile was queried to produce the derived shapefile?

Answer (score 7):

There easily might be multiple queries that return the same result. Using the following data:

```
FID STNAME  DIR
0   BLUE ST N
1   BLUE ST S
2   BLUE ST N
3   BLUE ST S
4   BLUE ST S
5   BLUE ST S
6   BLUE ST W
7   BLUE ST W
8   BLUE ST W
9   BLUE ST W
10  BLUE ST E
```

All these queries return the same thing:

```
"FID" < 6
"FID" < 6 AND "STNAME" = 'BLUE ST'
"FID" IN (0,1,2,3,4,5)
"DIR" = 'N' OR "DIR" = 'S'
"STNAME" = 'BLUE ST' AND "DIR" = 'N' OR "DIR" = 'S'
"FID" NOT IN (6,7,8,9,10) AND "STNAME" <> '' AND "DIR" = 'N' OR "DIR" = 'S'
```

There are an enormous amount of combinations that can be made, and I was only using three fields.

Comment: To expound upon this, the only way you will get the exact query that was run on your data is if the query was executed in a database that logs the queries that was run on it, such as a geodatabase stored in SQL server. Since you have noted that you are dealing with shapefiles, and not with a geodatabase that may have been backed by a logged RDBMS, the simple answer is no, you will not be able to retrieve the exact query that was run. ArcGIS does not log queries AFAIK. You can attempt to reverse engineer the query, but as Paul has noted, you will never be certain of the criteria.

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of what I thought, just throwing it out there.  It's good to know that geodatabases stored in SQL have a function that logs queries, though.  Thanks!

Comment: @jeff_fcco This Answer looks to me like it should be Accept-able which you can do by clicking on the green tick.

Answer (score 1):

If you use **Geoprocessing Tools** (Tools, Modelbuilder, Python) to create the derived shapefile (or feature class) you can view the [tool execution history](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002100000035000000). You find the history in:

- **history log file** (C:\Users\\AppData(Local or LocalLow or Roaming)\ESRI\Desktop10.1\ArcToolbox\History)
- in **metadata** of a tool's output data (see Item Description)